# Can we write $n!$ as $n^n$

Tags: asymptotics, factorial

I came to see the complexity analysis of an algorithm where it is written
$O(\log n!) \sim O(\log n^n) \sim O(n \log n)$.
My question is how could $n!$ be equivalent to $n^n$ or the article made some wrong assumption?

Comment: Read about Stirling approximation.

Comment: Did the article say some restriction to $n$? I'm referring to $n\rightarrow\infty$ or something like that. Read it again carefully and edit it if necessary.

Comment: $O(n!)$ is **not** the same as $O(n^n)$. But $O(log n!)$ **is** the same as $O(\log n^n)$,

Comment: Also, it's $O(logX)$, what refers to the "growing speed" of the function. It does not mean that $n!$ is equivalent to $n^n$, it's just saying that, when $n\rightarrow \infty$, both $log(n!)$ and $log(n^n)$ grow at the same speed. The second equivalence is trivial, because $log(x^y)=y\cdot log(x)$ by $log$ properties.

Comment: The only thing sort of wrong here is  $O(ln n^n) \sim O(n ln n)$ can be trivially made more strict by $O(ln n^n) = O(n ln n)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For large values of $n$,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation
this is known as stirling's approximation
$$\ln{n!} = n\ln n -n + O(\ln n)  $$
Hence,
$$ O(\ln{n!}) \approx O(n\ln n) $$
$$ = O(ln n^n)$$

Answer (score 1):

Write $\log n!=\sum_{k=1}^n\log k$ ; this sum can be approximated by the integral $\int_{1}^{n}\log x dx$ which is $\Theta(n\log n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach just using some simple algebra to compare $\log n!$ and $\log n^n$:

If $0\le k\le n-1$, then $n\le n+k(n-k-1)=(n-k)(k+1)$. It follows that

$$n^n\le(n\cdot1)((n-1)\cdot2)\cdots(2\cdot(n-1)(1\cdot n)=(n!)^2$$

and thus $n\log n\le 2\log n!$. Since

$$\log n!=\log n+\log(n-1)+\cdots+\log2+\log1\le\log n+\log n+\cdots+\log n+\log n=n\log n$$

is clear, we have

$${1\over2}n\log n\le\log n!\le n\log n$$

hence $O(\log n!)\sim O(\log n^n)=O(n\log n)$.